# Cannot active tensorflow on Windows using Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the instructions under the section 'Installing with Anaconda' on the page:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

When I run the command 'C:> activate tensorflow' in the third step, I am getting the below error:
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Attached an image for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE44P.jpg)

Appreciate if anyone can kindly help me.

Thanks,
Ramjee.

Comment: have you tried these steps using a cmd window?

Comment: Hi, yes. I have tried the cmd window and I get the same error there also.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the command `conda create -n tensorflow` in a cmd window, you are creating a new anaconda environment named `tensorflow`. It should be using the same python version your originally installed anaconda. Once it is done creating the environment, you activate the environment by calling `activate tensorflow`.

do you have anaconda properly installed? are you using a cmd window?

for example, see my cmd window. I have an environment call `python27`.[image]

Comment: Yes I have installed Anaconda. I have been using Spyder for the past few weeks to write Python programs. I was able to run Python programs successfully which makes me believe Python is also installed successfully.Now I wanted to install tensorflow and encountered this problem. I have tried using both Anaconda prompt and cmd prompt. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the command line error I got has mislead me. The truth is tensorflow isn't yet supported on Python 3.6 but supported only up to Python 3.5. 
Since I was using Anaconda's latest version which runs Python 3.6 by default, all the commands I input to active the tensorflow simply didn't work.

If you want to get tensorflow running, the solution is to create an Anaconda environment that runs on Python 3.5 and then continue with installation and activation of tensorflow.

It was a simple overlook that had cost me a couple of weeks but yet I had a good learning time.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem before, and finally solved this.

1. Right click 'My Computer', select 'Properties'.
2. Select 'advance system properties' → 'environment variable'
3. Add below to system variable and name it "PATH":

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

like this:[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nLBH.png)